# postgres: invalid argument: "psql"

Tags: linux, postgresql, sudo, psql

When I perform `sudo -u zorgan postgres psql` to start my postgres session it returns:

```
postgres: invalid argument: "psql"
```

if I remove `psql` it returns:

```
postgres does not know where to find the server configuration file.
You must specify the --config-file or -D invocation option or set the PGDATA environment variable.
```

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: depends on what you try to do... what you expect from `sudo -u zorgan postgres psql`?...

Comment: I'm simply trying to start a postgres session so I can create my database, similar to here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04#create-the-postgresql-database-and-user (however I'm doing this on my local server not a remote server)

Comment: `sudo -u zorgan postgres` will run a program  named `postgres` as the Linux user `zorgan` - I doubt that this is what you want. If you already have a user `zorgan` then why not just supply the username directly using:  `psql -U zorgan`

Comment: You _probably_ shouldn't run the `postgres` binary with `psql` as the argument, but the `psql` binary. Drop `postgres` out of that command line.

Comment: `sudo -u jameskrousoratis psql` returns `psql: FATAL:  database "zorgan" does not exist`

Comment: `sudo -u zorgan psql postgres`?..

Comment: YES! that starts the session - thankyou. `postgres=#  ..... `

Answer (score 2):

`sudo -u postgres psql`

The `postgres` above is a user.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.18/sudo.man.html

> [-u user] [command]

so in your case:

```
sudo -u zorgan postgres psql
```

tries to start postgres process with argument `psql` and thankfully fails.
if you want to connect to postgres cluster using `psql` client, use `psql`. so if you wish to run it with sudo:

```
sudo -u zorgan psql postgres
```

here postgres is argumentfor psql, which is dbname...

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html

> psql [option...] [dbname [username]]